# How can I write this with concurrency on Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Im having a problem with Thread that I couldn't understand.

```
public class Hurry{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lazy lazy = new Lazy();
        lazy.start();
        int contadorSegundos=0;
        while(lazy.isAlive()){
            if(contadorSegundos==5){
                lazy.interrupt();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" ¡¡Yo me voy!!");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" ¿Te queda mucho?");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                contadorSegundos++;
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}

        }//En clase no hemos conseguido la concurrencia, me has dicho que te ponga este comentario.
        if(contadorSegundos<5){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" ¡¡Por fin!");
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class Lazy extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        int aleatorio = ((int)(Math.random()*(9-2)+2));
        for(int i = 0; i<aleatorio;i++){
            switch ((int)(Math.random()*(4-1)+1)){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Me estoy vistiendo");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Me queda un segundo");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Esto no me queda bien");
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){}
            boolean xd = Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();
            if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" ¡¡Que cansino eres!");
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" ¡¡Ya estoy!");
        }

    }

}
```

Im practicing concurrency, and when the main executes lazy.interrupt(), the Thread lazy don't detects the interruption with Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted().
The code is supposed to detect when the main interrupts him, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Any idea? Many thanks!

Comment: If you read the Javadoc for `Thread.interrupt()`, this is mentioned: *If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int) methods of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an InterruptedException.*

Comment: Yes!!!!! That's exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks!